# Hiding Rows After a Certain Limit of Rows Has Been Updated

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to coding with a very basic understanding to Javascript. I created a table that will push an update to my tables upon clicking a button. However, i do want to limit the number of rows within my table. say for example upon pushing the sixth data to the table, i do want the first data to be removed from the row.

I tried searching everywhere with no luck. Maybe it's because my basic understand to javascript is pretty basic. Im a newbie haha. I am using vue.js for this code.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
           <input 
        type="number"  
        v-model="newElement.buy" 
                class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button 
        v-on:click="buyStock" 
        type="button" 
        class="btn btn-success mb-2">BUY
</button>
</form>

<section class="stock_tables">  
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">{{codeBuy}}</th>
    <th><a v-html="negative"></a> Buy</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr v-for="u in stocks">
    <th></th>
      <td>{{u.buy}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</section>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data: {
       codeBuy: "12345",
       stocks: [],
       newElement: {buy:"",sell:""}
  },
  methods: {
      buyStock: function(){
      this.stocks.push({buy:this.newElement.buy});
      this.newElement = {buy:""};
      }
   }
});
</script>
```

So basically everytime i enter the amount of the stocks and press buy it will update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some options to modify the `buyStock` method:

- `this.stocks.shift()`
- `this.$delete(this.stocks, 0)`
- `this.stocks = this.stocks.slice(1);`
- `this.stocks = this.stocks.slice(-5);`
- `this.stocks = this.stocks.splice(0, 1);`

or, without the `if` use:

```js
this.stocks = [...this.stocks, {
  buy: this.newElement.buy
}].slice(-5);
```

#### Demo below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    codeBuy: "12345",
    stocks: [],
    newElement: {
      buy: "",
      sell: ""
    },
    negative: ''
  },
  methods: {
    buyStock: function() {
      this.stocks.push({
        buy: this.newElement.buy
      });
      if (this.stocks.length > 5) {
        // this.$delete(this.stocks, 0);
        // this.stocks = this.stocks.slice(1);
        // this.stocks = this.stocks.slice(-5);
        // this.stocks = this.stocks.splice(0, 1);
        this.stocks.shift();
      }
      //this.stocks = [...this.stocks, {
      //  buy: this.newElement.buy
      //}].slice(-5);
      this.newElement = {
        buy: ""
      };
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
      <input type="number" v-model="newElement.buy" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button v-on:click="buyStock" type="button" class="btn btn-success mb-2">BUY</button>
  </form>

  <section class="stock_tables">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">{{codeBuy}}</th>
          <th><a v-html="negative"></a> Buy</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="u in stocks">
          <th></th>
          <td>{{u.buy}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</div>
```